# Passing comments to BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE macro

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, vivado-hls

`boost/mpl/list.hpp` has the following code:

```
#if !defined(BOOST_NEEDS_TOKEN_PASTING_OP_FOR_TOKENS_JUXTAPOSING)
#   define AUX778076_LIST_HEADER \
    BOOST_PP_CAT(list,BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_LIST_SIZE).hpp \
    /**/
#else
#   define AUX778076_LIST_HEADER \
    BOOST_PP_CAT(list,BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_LIST_SIZE)##.hpp \
    /**/
#endif

#   include BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(boost/mpl/list/AUX778076_LIST_HEADER)
#   undef AUX778076_LIST_HEADER
#endif
```

When I tried compiling it with the Vivado HLS C++ compiler, I get an error:

```
/usr/include/boost/mpl/list.hpp:36:13: fatal error: 'boost/mpl/list/list20.hpp /**/' file not found
#   include BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(boost/mpl/list/AUX778076_LIST_HEADER)
```

I concluded that the preprocessor appends the empty comment `/**/` to the filename being included. Removing it (with the preceding line's backslash `\`) solves the issue, although there are many other such empty comments causing new errors.

Why does the `AUX778076_LIST_HEADER` macro have this empty comment to begin with? Is it correct to expect `BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE` to remove it?

Comment: We can only guess that there is *some other* compiler that will fail if the empty comment is removed.

Comment: It's possible. Another guess would be that this is a convention to reduce line changes when changing a macro, like having a comma after the last enum value.

Comment: There's a `-CC` option to the GCC C preprocessor which causes this behaviour and I'm assuming there is some reason that HLS sets it. I use the following pretty horrible `sed` to strip out all of the offending comments - hope it helps someone. `find -name "*.hpp" -exec sed ':start /\\$/{N; s/\\$/\\/; t start; s:\\\n */\*\*/ *$::;}' -i '{}' ';'`

Comment: HLS does pass the `-CC` option to gcc, when invoking it for clang. It is seen for example in the `autopilot.flow.log` file: `Source preprocessing: exec clang -fno-limit-debug-info -gcc-toolchain "/opt/Xilinx/Vivado_HLS/2016.2/lnx64/tools/gcc" -hls -fno-exceptions  -D__llvm__  -CC -E ...` Perhaps this is needed for clang to generate correct line numbers?